# Openframeworks 0.10.0 iOS - running example in Simulator

Tags: openframeworks

Is ist possible to run Openframeworks iOS examples in the iOS Simulator?

I can build for real Device without Problems. But for Simulator build will fail with error.

Tank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

1. You should download the correct and most recent openFrameworks IOS release to compile it successfully.
2. Check the IOS Simulator versions. If they are out of date or old, you'll need to update the simulators from XCode->Preferences->Components menu.
3. When building for IOS simulators you need to select the related simulator from XCode "Set Active Scheme" tab as following;

[image: screenshot]

4. You need to set Bundle Identifier e.g com.yourName.ProjectName in XCode project General settings

[image: screenshot]

5. You need to select an active developer account from Signing section in XCode project General settings
6. Check your target device version and openFrameworks version.